# JavaScript Definition pause()

Tags: javascript

Does anyone know what the proper definition for the code below.  It is inside my function and it is frustrating not knowing the correct name for it...  Thank you.

pause()

Comment: So we're supposed to guess what you want it to do based on the name?

Comment: `pause()` is not a standard JS function.

Comment: you can't pause execution flow for a specific period of time in JS without using showModalDialog(), which not all browsers support, and it has an ugly popup during the pause... well, ok, another crappy option is to use sync ajax and a server-side script with a delayed return, but that's not all JS...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This method is used for media elements
[HTML Audio/Video DOM pause() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_met_pause.asp)

Comment: Why downvote this answer? It may well be correct; it depends on what the question is really about. It would be better if it said *what* the `pause` method on media elements does, but to say it's "not useful" seems incorrect. Downvoting because someone *tried* to help even though the question was poor is inappropriate.

Answer (score 1):

***Guessing***, based on the name, you want it to make the JavaScript thread on which the function is called pause before continuing.

You can't do that.

What you do *instead* is schedule a timed callback, like this:

```
function yourFunction() {
    doSomething();
    setTimeout(function() {
        doSomethingElseLater();
    }, 500);
}
```

There, when you call `yourFunction`, `doSomething` happens immediately, `setTimeout` is called, and `yourFunction` returns. **Later**, the timer expires and `doSomethingElseLater` (and anything else inside the function you gave `setTimeout`) is called.